# Are these definitions of a congruence relation equivalent?

Tags: category-theory

I found a definition of a congruence relation on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence) which I will summarize below.

In a finitely complete category $C$, a congruence on an object $X$ is a subobject of $X \times X$ with injections $p$ and $q$, together with three morphisms

- $r\colon X \rightarrow R$ which is a section of both $p$ and $q$
- $s\colon R \rightarrow R$ which interchanges $p$ and $q$
- $t\colon R \times_X R \rightarrow R$ which factors the left and right projection map $R \times_X R \rightarrow X \times X$ through $R$

I also remember seeing a congruence relation defined in [JoyOfCats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) as a pair $(p,q)$ where
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>{p}>> \bullet \\
@VqVV @VVfV \\
\bullet @>{f}>> \bullet
\end{CD}
form a pullback square for some $f$.

I'm curious if these definitions are equivalent. I can almost see that the latter definition implies the first since if we assume that the following diagram is a pullback square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C @>{p}>> A \\
@VqVV @VVfV \\
A @>{f}>> B
\end{CD}
Then by replacing $p$ and $q$ from $A$ with $1_A$ from $A$ to $A$ this will induce an arrow $r:A \rightarrow C$ such that $r \circ p = 1_A$ and $r \circ q =1_A$. Next by replacing $p$ by $q$ and $q$ by $p$ this induces an arrow $s:C \rightarrow C$ such that $s \circ p =q$ and $s \circ q = p$. Finally by replacing $p$ by the composite $p \circ \pi_1$ (where $\pi$ is the cannonical projection $C \times C \rightarrow C$ onto the first coordinate) and replace $q$ by $q \circ \pi_2$ we induce a map $t: C \times C \rightarrow C$ which factors the left and right peojections through $C$. Now I would just need that $C$ is a subobject of $A \times A$, which I'm unsure about.

The reverse direction I am even more unsure about, I don't see why the square would need to be pullback assuming the properties in the first definition. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions are inequivalent in general.
The definition you found on nLab is the conventional definition.
The other definition you found is that of "kernel pair".

As you observe, every kernel pair is a congruence.
Conversely, a congruence that is also the kernel pair of a regular epimorphism is said to be "effective".
In a regular category, any congruence that is also a kernel pair of *some* morphism is automatically effective.
In a Barr exact category, any congruence whatsoever is effective.
In general, there may be ineffective congruences.
For example, in the category of topological spaces, although every congruence has a coequaliser, and every kernel pair is effective, not every congruence is a kernel pair.